# How to stop <router-link> from sending the user to another page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a logic like this: is the user is V2 use the user to the url in `subHeaderRouter.router`. If the user isn't launch `this.openModal`:

```
<router-link
  v-for="subHeaderRouter in subHeaderRouters"
  :to="subHeaderRouter.router"
  @click="handleOpenModal()">
</router-link>

handleOpenModal () {
  if (this.IsV2User) return
  this.openModal('changeUserType', 'user.changeUserType')
}
```

The only thing I need to do now is to stop `:to` then she user is not V2. How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can prevent the default `<router-link>` behavior by specifying no [default event](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#event) to listen to and handling the `click` event manually with the `.native` modifier:

```
<router-link
  v-for="subHeaderRouter in subHeaderRouters"
  event=""
  :to="subHeaderRouter.router"
  @click.native.prevent="handleOpenModal(subHeaderRouter.router)"/>
```

```
handleOpenModal(route) {
    if (this.IsV2User) {
        this.$router.push(route)
    } else {
        this.openModal('changeUserType', 'user.changeUserType')
    }
}
```

If the `event=""` seems weird to you, it also works with an empty attribute:

```
<router-link
  v-for="subHeaderRouter in subHeaderRouters"
  event
  :to="subHeaderRouter.router"
  @click.native.prevent="handleOpenModal(subHeaderRouter.router)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. You must be a Vue veteran.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it partly works though. I manage to get the function in `@click.native.prevent=` to work but somehow not able to prevent the page from being redirected to the route in `:to`. Could someone please give me a pointer?

Comment: See my answer below if you are after (a solution for Vue3)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/68083283/7362226]

Answer (score 9):

## Vue 3 Solution

In Vue3, the `event` has been [removed](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#Removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link-) from `"<router-link>`, you will need to use [v-slot API](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-s-v-slot) instead.

```vue
 <router-link :to="yourRoute" custom v-slot="{ href, navigate }">
    <a v-if="yourBoolean" @click="handleEvent()">Run the function</a>
    <a
        v-else
        :href="href"
        @click="navigate">
        Go to route in "to"
    </a>
</router-link>
```

```vue
// Vue 3 Composition API

export default {  
    setup() {
        const handleEvent = () => {
            
           // Add your logic here
      
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `custom` is the important attribute inside `router-link` component, so you can insert your own link elements..

Comment: How can I use this if I've set up custom `NavLink` and `AppLink` views that contain a `router-link` with a `<slot>???</slot>` inside?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used dynamic Vue Components as solution. You will also have to check the difference in styling for router and div tag.

```
<component 
  :is=" condition ? 'router-link' : 'div' "
  @click="handleOpenModal"  
  :to="your_link">
</component>
```